# Build a PHP array from a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create array from multiple rows. In My table I have `Year` field, `regd` field for counting the number of students, and `Class` field. I want to output the data like below.

```
$data = array( 
              '2012' => array(
                             'KG_I' => 87,
                             'KG_II' => 80,
                             'I' => 90,
                             'II' => 120,
                             'III' => 100,
                             'IV' => 110,
                             'V' => 98,
             ),
             '2013' => array(
                             'KG_I' => 82,
                             'KG_II' => 84,
                             'I' => 92,
                             'II' => 110,
                             'III' => 120,
                             'IV' => 108,
                             'V' => 90,
             ),
            '2014' => array(
                            'KG_I' => 90,
                            'KG_II' => 83,
                            'I' => 95,
                            'II' => 110,
                            'III' => 120,
                            'IV' => 81,
                            'V' => 95,
            ),
  );
```

My attempt was like this:

```
$std=array();
$hms="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT regd) as stdNum, Class, Year FROM 
      student GROUP by Class";
$quar=mysql_query($hms);
$myarray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($quar)){
    $myarray[$row['Class']] = $row['stdNum'];
}
```

I have no idea how I output the Year array.

Comment: It should be GROUP by Year then class i.e. `GROUP BY Year, Class`

Comment: If you think you have a problem with your SQL query, you should export your student table, so we could try a test.

Comment: It might be helpful to provide a SQL Fiddle here, so we can see your test data. Some people will even fork it for you and offer a suggested query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You opened two arrays which is not necessary. `print_r()` may come handy when dealing with arrays. Hope this will help.

```
$hms="Select Year, Class, COUNT(DISTINCT regd) as stdNum 
      from student group by Year, Class";
$quar=mysql_query($hms);
$myArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quar)){
    $mya[$row['Year']][$row['Class']] =  $row['stdNum'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($quar)){
    $myarray[$row['Year']][$row['Class']] = $row['stdNum'];
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: You did not mention how I output. My output did not show Year array.

Comment: Ah, I commented on this as having a syntax error, but I see what you are doing now. I'd create intermediate variables for `$year` and `$class` for that reason, but +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$std=array();
$hms="Select Year,Class,count(regd) 'stdNum' from       student group by Year,Class";
$quar=mysql_query($hms);
$myarray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($quar)){
    $myarray[$row['Year']]$row['Class']] =      $row['stdNum'];
}
```